# Reactive UI combining combining observables

Tags: c#, blazor, reactiveui

I'm trying to build registration wizard for my application. Target framework is .NET Core 3.1 and Blazor Server. What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. On first page user should be be able to enter needed informations and can proceed only if validation is valid.
2. On the second page there are additional forms.

Here is my attempt for combining observables and creating single reactive command:

```
    public sealed class CompanyViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _address;
        private string _vatNumber;
        private bool _euBased;
        private string _website;
        private Guid _headQuarterLocation;
        private Guid _primarySector;
        public readonly IObservable<bool> IsValidObservable;

        public CompanyViewModel()
        {
            IsValidObservable = this.WhenAnyValue
                 (
                     x => x.Name,
                     x => x.Address,
                     x => x.VatNumber,
                     x => x.EuBased,
                     x => x.HeadquarterLocation,
                 (name, address, vatNumbner, euBased, headquarterLocation) =>
                 {
                     return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(address) &&
                            !headquarterLocation.Equals(default) &&
                            !(euBased && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vatNumbner));
                 });
        }
}

    public sealed class CompanyEmployeeViewModel : ReactiveObject, IDisposable
    {
        private Guid _employeeId;
        private Guid _companyId;
        private Guid _workingPositionId;
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private string _email;
        private string _phoneNumber;
        private bool _isCompanyRepresentative;
        private bool _canAllowProject;
        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isValid;

        public CompanyEmployeeViewModel()
        {
           this.WhenAnyValue
                (
                    x => x.CompanyId,
                    x => x.WorkingPosition,
                    x => x.FirstName,
                    x => x.LastName,
                    x => x.Email
                 )
                .Select(values => IsPopulated(values.Item1, values.Item2, values.Item3, values.Item4, values.Item5))
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsValid, out _isValid);

        }
}



   public sealed class CompanyRegistrationWizardViewModel :  ReactiveObject
    {
        public readonly CompanyViewModel Company;
        private CompanyRegistrationWizardStep _currentStep;
        private SourceList<CompanyEmployeeViewModel> _employees;
        private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> _nextStep;
        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _currentStepIsValid;

        public CompanyRegistrationWizardViewModel(CompanyViewModel companyRegVm)
        {
            Company = companyRegVm;
            _currentStep = CompanyRegistrationWizardStep.CompanyProfileCreation;
            _employees = new SourceList<CompanyEmployeeViewModel>();

            var employeesValidationObservable = _employees.Connect().WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.IsValid).Select(x => x.Value);

            var canProceedToNextStepValidatorObservable
                = Observable.CombineLatest(Company.IsValidObservable, employeesValidationObservable)
                 .Select(x => CurrentStep == CompanyRegistrationWizardStep.CompanyEmployeeDetails ? x[0] : x[1]);

            canProceedToNextStepValidatorObservable.ToProperty(this, x => x.CurrentStepIsValid, out _currentStepIsValid);
            _nextStep = ReactiveCommand.Create(ResolveNextStep, canProceedToNextStepValidatorObservable);
        }
}
```

Validation for company view model and employee is working fine and I can see if IsValid property true but I can't figure out how to merge those observales so that I can have only one command for proceeding to the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Observable.Merge` will take two observables and merge them.  You can then subscribe to that new observable of the merge.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html